# how is this EXPLAIN ANALYZE syntax wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

While attempting to do my postgres lesson, I can't seem to get EXPLAIN ANALYZE to work.

The book says this

[image]

and since pasting or shift-returning in my console doesn't do multi-line entries, I did the following - and got nowhere.

```
shine_development-> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lower(first_name) like 'bob%' OR lower(last_name) like 'bob%' OR lower(email) = 'bob@example.com' ORDER BY email = 'bob@example.com' DESC, last_name ASC; QUERY PLAN
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "QUERY"
LINE 1: QUERY PLAN
    ^
```

What is the right way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `QUERY PLAN` that is part of the result. Is the Header / FieldName for the result

Comment: yep - I was trying it without QUERY PLAN before and it was failing for some other reason, but this time it worked - thanks!